# replace multiple characters for folder-names

Tags: python, replace

I'm on Windows and Windows does not like the characters '?/"|:*<>' for folder-names. Now I wan't to replace said characters with '_'. It seems to work if I `.replace(':', '_')` but not with any other character. But anyway, I want to replace all the above characters. I tried `(somestring).replace(':', '_').replace('?', '_')` but it does not work.

How it is right now:

```
with open(unidecode(somestring).replace(':', '_')+'/{0}_{1}.txt'.format(counter, points), 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as outfile: outfile.write('{0}\n\n{1}\n'.format(stringhere, somecontent))
```

As said, it replaces the ':' just fine. But no other character. How can I replace multiple characters in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex`

```
import re
fe = '?/"|:*<>?/abcdefg"|:*<>'
ke = re.sub(r'[?/"|:*<>]', '_', fe)

>>> fe
'?/"|:*<>?/abcdefg"|:*<>'

>>> ke
'__________abcdefg______'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
res = ''.join(['_' if letter in '?/"|:*<>' else letter for letter in fe])
print(res)
#__________abcdefg______
```